# How to upgrade from Centos 7.1 to 7.2?

Tags: centos, yum

The software I'm using is only supported by CentOS 7.2.

I tried

```
sudo yum --releasever=7.2 update
```

and get

> Cannot find a valid basurl for repo: base/7.2/x86_64.

With

```
sudo yum update
```

takes me to 7.3

Comment: try --releasever=7.2.1511

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CentOS 7.2 actual version is 7.2.1511 and uses this URL

http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/

Try `yum --releasever=7.2.1511 update`

You can also try to edit `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo`, and change baseurl to

```
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/
```

instead of

```
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
```

Comment: I changed the baseurls as said and commented out the mirrorlist. I'm getting Damaged repomd.xml . OK yum clean all fixed that.

Comment: The full edit, repeated under [base], [updates], and [extras]
`[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.2.115/os/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7`

then yum clean all

Comment: At the moment http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.2.1511/readme contains the following text: 
```This directory (and version of CentOS) is deprecated.  For normal users,
you should use /7/ and not /7.2.1511/ in your path.``` ... ```If you know what you are doing, and absolutely want to remain at the 7.2.1511
level, go to http://vault.centos.org/ for packages. ```

Comment: They archived it, you can access it at http://vault.centos.org/7.2.1511/

Answer (score 1):

Below line worked for me:-

1) vi /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo

2) Replace baseurl:-
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/

3) yum --releasever=7.2.1511 update --skip-broken

and finally check -- cat /etc/redhat-release